# c# - Console.Clear() don't clear text from other methods

Tags: c#

I am making simple PRG in console.
In my `MenuSystem` `Console.Clear()` does not clear text from other methods.
Any ideas?

```
class MenuSystem
{
    public static void Controll(int count, List<String> texts)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int index = 0;
        bool isEnter = false;
        Write(0, texts);

        while (!isEnter)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    index -= 1;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    index += 1;
                    break;
            }

            if (index > (count - 1))
                index = 0;
            else if (index < 0)
                index = count - 1;

            Write(index, texts);
        }
    }

    private static void Write(int index, List<String> texts)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        texts[index] = "[ " + texts[index] + " ]";

        foreach (String text in texts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Console.Clear() in `Write()` does not clear console.

Comment: First of all, Windows console is too slow for this task. As an option, you can use .NET Core and execute it in Linux bash, which is faster afaik. Also your code does not compile, because you mixed up `index` and `count` in `Control` method.

Comment: After fixing the code I am not getting any issues with writing to the console then calling your code, which then clears the console and writes the collection of strings. Do you have additional code that could be causing the issue?

Comment: It does clear the console but you are wrapping the text with `[]` each time you go through the loop. Also it will not clear the console until you press a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is not with `Console.Clear` (whose *only* purpose is to clear the screen, not *"clear text from other methods"* as you suggested.

The problem is that you're modifying an element in your array, then modifying a new element in the array without un-modifying the previous one. If you wanted to solve this problem using your current method, then you would need to track which item you previously modified in a class-level variable so you can un-modify it when the user changes the selection.

However, I would suggest a different approach. Instead of modifying the strings in your list, you should just change the way you *display* the information, not the information itself.

So, after applying your logic to detect which index to select, you just loop through the menu items and write them to the screen, and when you get to the index of the item that's selected, you write the "[" and "]" characters around it. For the other menu items, you should surround them with an empty space character, so they aren't moving all over the place as the selections change.

Note that I also made a small change to have the menu display horizontally:

```
class MenuSystem
{
    public static void Control(List<string> menuItems)
    {
        var selectedIndex = 0;
        var exitMenu = false;

        while (!exitMenu)
        {
            DisplayMenu(selectedIndex, menuItems);

            switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    selectedIndex -= 1;
                    if (selectedIndex < 0) selectedIndex = menuItems.Count - 1;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    selectedIndex += 1;
                    if (selectedIndex > menuItems.Count - 1) selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    exitMenu = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DisplayMenu(int selectedIndex, List<string> menuItems)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == selectedIndex)
            {
                Console.Write("[" + menuItems[i] + "]");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" " + menuItems[i] + " ");
            }

            Console.Write("  ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really an answer to your question but merely a demonstration that the code you have posted does work.

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Some Text");           
    Console.Read(); //Console shows Show Text 
    MenuSystem.Controll(1, new List<string>() { "string" });
    Console.Read(); //Console shows string
}

...
class MenuSystem
{
    public static void Controll(int count, List<String> texts)
    {
        Write(count, texts);
    }

    private static void Write(int index, List<String> texts) //I don't know why you are passing index as it is never used here.
    {
        Console.Clear(); //Console is now cleared

        foreach (String text in texts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text); 
        }
    }
}
```

As the code you have provided is working I can only presume that there is some other logic in your full code that is causing the issue.

Please update your question with code that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The example is far from perfect, but you will get the sense of using `Console.Clear()`:

```
class Program
{
    static void DrawPlayer(int x, int y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            Console.WriteLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            Console.Write(' ');
        Console.Write("\u25A0");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int playerX = 0, playerY = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            DrawPlayer(playerX, playerY);
            var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
            switch (keyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.W:
                    playerY--;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.A:
                    playerX--;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.S:
                    playerY++;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D:
                    playerX++;
                    break;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```